# How to make auctex not prompt me on C-c C-c

Tags: auctex

The C-c C-c bind runs TeX-command-master. It always asks me "is this what you want to do?" and I'm always hitting return to do it. I'd like a version of this command which just does it without asking.

Comment: you can click on the `TeX` or `LaTeX` icon in the tool bar to by-pass the `C-cC-c` access to these specific commands. Besides `C-cC-c` has automatic completion which is useful as you only need to type the first or first view later of the command you need from the command menu.

Comment: C-c C-c is not only used to launch `LaTeX` but also `Bibtex`, `Biber`, cleaning, ... This is why pressing Return is important (it shows that you selected one choice).

Comment: @ ppr: I understand the command, and that it has its place. I will use the TeX-command-master command sometimes, but I would like a different command in addition. I know ahead of time that I want the default, so pressing return is not "important", it is an annoying waste of my time.

Comment: @ jfbu: I understand that, and I do not want that.

Comment: @IanKelling See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132927/run-tex-command-master-without-querying-in-emacs

Comment: @IanKelling ok, (advice: no space between the `@` and the intended recipient). In my comment above `first view later` meant `first few letters` (took me 5 minutes to figure it out), sorry about this discomforting sample of the functioning of my brain ...

Answer (score 2):

This does C-c C-c return, and then return again if we are still in the minibuffer.

It is not extensively tested. A more proper solution would not use keyboard macros, but this works fine.

Standard elisp disclaimer: You may want to change the binding, or make it into a named function instead of a lambda.

```el
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (define-key LaTeX-mode-map
   (kbd "<f7>")
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p")
     (progn
       (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([3 3 return] 0 "%d")) arg)
       (and
        (derived-mode-p 'minibuffer-inactive-mode)
        (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([return] 0 "%d")) arg))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently found `C-c C-a` (bound to `TeX-command-run-all`) which does exactly this.

Comment: This works. Best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the TeX command you want, mine is XeLaTex. Then you don't need to hit return.

```
(setq TeX-command-force "XeLaTeX")
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the command to still make the appropriate choice (LaTeX, Biber, View,...), not just run one fixed command.

Answer (score 1):

Put his in your .emacs or init.el, you can get all info from the comment

```
;; compile documents to PDF by default
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
;; C-c C-c without prompt, use LaTex by default
(setq TeX-command-force "LaTex")
;; Use C-c C-c to compile the tex file into pdf file automatically using LaTex,
;; and C-c C-v to view it using okular
;; NOTE: C-c C-a to combine C-c C-c and C-c C-v"
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "okular -p %(outpage) %o")))
```

If you use evince, change the "PDF Viewer..." line into

```
'(("PDF viewer" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
```